# unable to render norton security image in angular app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, android-lazyloading

When adding a reference to the norton security logo JS file (copied below) via a partial html file, I received the following error:

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened
```

Instead of using a lazy load library or angular changes, I used the JQuery document ready call to load up the JS file but I am not experiencing the desired behavior i.e. the Norton logo does not get loaded up.

```
<div id="sslLogo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function loadLogo(sslLogoContainer) {
 "use strict";

  var sslLogoScript = document.createElement('script');
  sslLogoScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  sslLogoScript.src = 'https://seal.websecurity.norton.com/getseal?host_name=www.test.com&amp;size=L&amp;use_flash=NO&amp;use_transparent=NO&amp;lang=en';
  sslLogoContainer.appendChild(sslLogoScript);

}

$(document).ready(function () {
var sslLogoContainer = document.getElementById("sslLogo");
loadLogo(sslLogoContainer);
});

/*
window.onload = {
var sslLogoContainer = document.getElementById("sslLogo");
loadLogo();
}*/
</script>
```

Any thoughts on how to fix the issue?  I modified the norton url for stackoverflow.

Comment: That `src` doesn't look like it's a `.js` file.

Comment: it points to a JS file

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't seem like it contains anything that would load an image (`x=1`). And why not simply add it as an image inside a `img` tag?

Comment: this is a symantec js file that creates their seal on a website. I replaced the URL with test.com for stackoverflow

Comment: Any resolution to this issue. Am too facing this same issue..

Comment: I found this issue before (I was having the same issue) so I posted my answer there: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744864/how-to-setup-norton-seal-for-angularjs-site

Comment: thank you for sharing @FlorianTopf